# Navigation bar top and bottom padding through CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to increase the top and bottom padding in the following, but can't get it to work. I.e. notice the padding top and bottom code in `ul.navbar li a`. It has no effect. What's an alternative? Please advise.

```css
    ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ff9933;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    ul.navbar li {
        margin: auto;
        display: inline;
        border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
    }

    ul.navbar li:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
    }

    ul.navbar li a {
        display: inline;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.navbar li a:hover {
        background-color: #e67300;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Photos</a></li><li><a href="#">Videos</a></li><li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't want to disturb the navigation bar's layout in any way - hence can't include the padding top and bottom option in `<ul>` - that messes up the layout and the hover both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inline` elements don't have top and bottom padding. If you want to these padding you must use `block` or `inline-block` elements:

```css
ul.navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff9933;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.navbar li {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

ul.navbar li:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #ffb366;
}

ul.navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #e67300;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Photos</a></li><li><a href="#">Videos</a></li><li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

[9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes.

You can set it to inline block, if you need to apply vertical paddings etc.

```
ul.navbar li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```